# how to fix the torch.cuda.is_available() False problem without restarting the machine?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pytorch

I have:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 19:59:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> torch.cuda.is_available()
False
>>> quit()

$ nvidia-smi
Wed Oct 14 21:28:50 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.06    Driver Version: 450.51.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2070    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P8     9W /  N/A |   1257MiB /  7982MiB |     11%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1424      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                823MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1767      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              407MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6420      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6949      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7447      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8888      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9218      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9282      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     65854      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     70801      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox            2MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there a way I could fix this problem without having to restart my machine?

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and PyTorch 1.6.0

After I restarted the machine, here's what I get:
[image]

Comment: I think its likely that you could set up an anaconda environment on that machine that would work with pytorch `conda install pytorch torchvision cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`  see [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/).  Your 450.xx driver will work fine with CUDA 10.2

Comment: I don't have any problem with my driver's version and for the most part it works. Occasionally this error happens which I have to restart the machine to get it fixed

Answer (score 6):

This happens quite often to ubuntu users (I am not so sure about other distros). I have noticed this behavior especially when I leave my machine on sleep. Without restarting you could run the following commands as mentioned in this [thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/cuda-runtime-error-999/69658/19)

`sudo rmmod nvidia_uvm` 
`sudo modprobe nvidia_uvm`